# What's a good resource for Hormander symbols of type (1/2, 1/2)?

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, micro-local-analysis

I'm currently working with some pseudodifferential operators of Hormander class $L^{m}_{\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}}$ and unfortunately many of the usual tools break down, due to difficulties with their asymptotic expansion. In particular, I know a version of Egorov's theorem holds for such operators, but the reference I know for that result (Taylor's *Pseudodifferential Operators*) is out of print and difficult to find. He doesn't cover this case in the second volume of *Partial Differential Equations*, either.

Hormander briefly mentions this class in volume three of *The Analysis of Linear Partial Differential Operators*, but doesn't provide much guidance on how to modify Egorov's theorem.

Is there a better reference for this fact, and for this exotic symbol class in general? I feel a bit bad about referring to Taylor's book when I know copies of it are few and far between.

Comment: You should clarify your expectations for Egorov theorem in that class; what is likely to happen is that the remainder will have the same order than the main term.